# Rails 4 before_action being invoked as if within Mime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm at a loss. The below is supposed to be invoking `api_authenticate_data_check` if it exists, but it fails with the following error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Mime::API_AUTHENTICATE_DATA_CHECK):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:48:in `api_authenticate'
```

Why the expletive does Rails think that we're inside of the `Mime` object? And why is the same issue not present in the `send` directly above?! None of my controllers do anything related to `Mime` -- not directly anyway.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :api_authenticate

  def api_authenticate
    model_name = controller_name[0...-1]
    params_name = "#{model_name}_params".to_sym

    # below works
    p = (respond_to?(params_name) ? send(params_name) : params)[model_name]

    # below does *not* work (line 48)
    valid_data = !respond_to(:api_authenticate_data_check) || send(:api_authenticate_data_check, p)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you forgot the question mark(?) at the end of respond_to. The correct method is respond_to?. The respond_to without question mark is a method of rails controller which will check the MIME type of the given param so that it can respond with correct MIME type headers.